# RxJava callback for last onNext() execution finished

Tags: java, android, synchronization, rx-java

I'm new to RxJava. I would like to download some data for each `TempoAccount` entity from given collection and store it all in a map `accountsWithProjects`. When the code of last `onNext(TempoAccount tempoAccount)` is completed I'd like to call `filterAccountsWithProjects(accountsWithProjects)` method. Is there some simple way to achieve it?

```
private void getProjectsForEachTempoAccount(Collection<TempoAccount> tempoAccounts) {
    final Map<TempoAccount, Collection<TempoProject>> accountsWithProjects =
            new HashMap<>(tempoAccounts.size());
    Observable<TempoAccount> accountsObservable = Observable.from(tempoAccounts);
    accountsObservable
            .compose(ObservableUtils.applySchedulers())
            .subscribe(new ObserverAdapter<TempoAccount>() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    view.notifyAboutError(e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(TempoAccount tempoAccount) {
                    jira.requestProjectsInfoForTempoAccount(String.valueOf(tempoAccount.getId()))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(new ObserverAdapter<Collection<TempoProject>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                    view.notifyAboutError(e.getMessage());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNext(Collection<TempoProject> projects) {
                                    accountsWithProjects.put(tempoAccount, projects);
                                }

                            });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    filterAccountsWithProjects(accountsWithProjects);
                }
            });
}
```

**Problem:** In the code above `filterAccountsWithProjects(accountsWithProjects)` is fired before all observables from `onNext(TempoAccount tempoAccount)` are completed.

**Edit:**

I want to create an Observable of such a type: `Observable<Map<TempoAccount, Collection<TempoProject>>`.
I have two observables given:

1. `Observable<TempoAccount> accountsObservable = Observable.from(tempoAccounts)`
2. `Observable<Collection<TempoProject>> projectsForAccountObservable = jira.requestProjectsInfoForTempoAccount(TempoAccount account)`

**So my questions is**: can I connnect them somehow and create the map having these two observables.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `flatMap()` function on your original stream to do the things you are currently doing in the `onNext()`. Also, you don't need to filter the stream in `onComplete()`. You could use `filter()` on the stream itself and deal with the problem in a more "Reactive" way.

Here is an example:

```
 accountsObservable
        .compose(ObservableUtils.applySchedulers())
        .map(tempoAccount -> new Pair<TempoAccount, Collection<TempoProject>>(tempoAccount, fetchInfoAccountForTempoAccount(tempoAccount)))
        .filter(pair -> hasProjects(pair))
        .toMap(pair -> pair.first(), pair -> pair.second)
        .subscribe(...)
```

**EDIT:**

Updated the suggested answer - you get the `TempoAccount`s, then you map each account to a `Pair` of account and collection of `TempoProject`s. You filter the pairs to see if you have any projects and then you use `toMap()` to create your desired result. Be aware, that to get `toMap()` working, your observables have to call `onComplete()` when the end of the stream is reached.

Comment: The `flatMap()` removes information about `TempoAccount` objects. The thing  i need at the end is to get collection of  such `TempoAccount` objects that `Collection<TempoProject>` associated with them contains `TempoProject` object with desired `key` value (some field). Not sure if It's clear enough :)

Comment: It depends. `flatMap()` can produce a whole new stream for a value, `map()` transforms the value into a new one. It all depends on your use case :)

Comment: I'd like to transform stream of `TempoAccount` objects to stream of `Map.Entry<TempoAccount, Collection<TempoProject>>`. Is there some transforming method to achieve this that would take `Observable<TempoAccount>` as a param? The `map()` method takes directly the `Map.Value` type so it's not the choice for me.

Comment: What is the exact result that you need from your method?

Comment: I have collection of `TempoAccount` objects. For each object I want to fetch collection of `TempoProject` objects and put into Map. At the end I want to get `Map<TempoAccount, Collection<TempoProject>> accountsWithProjects`.

Comment: I've got method `Observable<Collection<TempoProject>> getProjects(TempoAccount account)` too.

Comment: @samiuel I think I have a better suggestion for your use case. Check the edit.

Comment: I understand your idea but there is one problem. I don't have explicit `Collection<TempoProject>` to be passed in `new Pair()` constructor but an `Observable<TempoProject>` stream. I tried to convert it to collection like this: `requestProjectsInfoForTempoAccount(tempoAccount)
                                    .compose(ObservableUtils.applySchedulers())
                                    .toList()
                                    .toBlocking()
                                    .single()` but it freezes my device and it's not responding.

Comment: Maybe you can try out `zip` or something to merge the two streams together.